# usage of $ref to define individual (reusable) properties

Tags: swagger, openapi

Is this possible/correct (shows ok in swagger ui but code gen produces empty classes):

```
definitions:  
  name_and_abn:
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        $ref: "#/definitions/entityName"
      abn:
        $ref: "#/definitions/abn"
  abn:
       type: string
       minLength: 11
       maxLength: 11
       pattern: "^[0-9]{11}$"
  entityName:
       type: string
       maxLength: 1000
       pattern: '^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,50}$'
```

If not, is there a way I can reuse field definitions in OpenApi3?

In other words, are objects the only types that can be referenced ($ref) from schema objects?

Thanks

Comment: Your spec is correct. If there's a problem with codegen, file a bug report in the [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) repository.